# Distort a straight line via fisheye distortion function and draw it correctly in image

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, fisheye

I have a line in world coordinates and project it to an image (as described in this question [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811665/how-to-project-a-3d-line-represented-in-pl%C3%BCcker-coordinates-into-2d-image/1815682#1815682)). This results in a simple line equation in image space, so I can easily print it with OpenCV inside an image.

Now I want to project the line into a fisheye camera image. Since I have a corresponding non-linear distortion function I'm able to distort points easily. The naive way is now to distort each point from the generated line via this function. But that would lead to several line segments and unset pixels (which would normally belong to the distorted line).

I wonder what could be a clever way to get a correct distorted line. Maybe it is also necessary to handle the line projection in a different way? I could sample the straigt line more often (i.e. using subpixel coordinates), but I think that don't guarantee me a correct solution.

EDIT:

My distortion function is a simple polynom

```
r(a) = k1*a+k2*a^2+k3*a^3+k4*a^4
```

where `a` is the angle of the undistorted incident ray to the optical axis and `r` is the radius to a pixel in the distorted image. Your can read more about that [here](http://www.lce.hut.fi/research/mm/calibration/Kannala_Brandt_ICPR2004.pdf).

Comment: Please post (or point to) the equations of the lens distortion model you intend to use.

Comment: @FrancescoCallari : I added the information in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is indeed to increase your line resolution.
If you add more pixels (sub-pixels are better), then you will get a better looking image after the distortion.

I think the more correct way is **backward-mapping**. Find the mapping from each pixel (square,integer) in the *distorted* image into the pixel (quadrilateral, real) in the *undistorted* image.
This will make sure you won't have any holes in your distorted line.

[image]

Comment: I already have a lookup table with the corresponding backward mapping. Since I have a line equation in the undistorted image I could calculate the line in the distorted image, as you said. But that means, for one line I have to test every pixel in the distorted image if the line equation holds. Or is there a trick I can use to speed this procedure up.

Comment: @Vaniax. First, its not always easy to inverse the mapping. In normal cameras, given the distortion coefficients, the mapping from undistorted to distorted is easy, but the other way involves iterative solution (x and y are coupled). Luckily for you, the model you are using is inversible, so there shouldn't be any accuracy issues.
Second, I'm already assuming you have created a pixel image in the undistorted image, I'm not talking about the original line equation.
Why you are so concerned about speed? the main factor is the interpolation you will do to get the pixel value.